# Why can't I see a type ahead block within two blocks in a Omniscript?

Tags: fields, vlocity

Could anyone tell me why I can't display a Type Ahead Block that is within 2 Blocks? How do I get it displayed in this condition?
The example in the picture, TypeAhead3 is not being displayed. I would like to understand why.

Ps: TypeAhead3 and TypeAhead4 are the same and do not have any custom settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known product behavior mentioned on [page 137](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362007/why-cant-i-see-a-type-ahead-block-within-two-blocks-in-a-omniscript#:%7E:text=developer.salesforce.com/files/credential%2Dresources/%E2%80%A6).

> If a Type Ahead Block exists in a Block element, only one Block
> element is permitted. Adding multiple nested Blocks will result in
> errors.

Comment: Page 137 of https://developer.salesforce.com/files/credential-resources/OmniStudio-Documentation.pdf